# Python: How to test how many times a method is called without replacing the original method?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Here is an over simplified example:

```
class Foo:
    def say_it(self):
        return self.say()

    def say(self):
        print("Hello!")
        return 123


def test_call_count():
    with patch("Foo.say") as say_call:
        amount = Foo().say_it()
    assert amount == 123
    assert say_call.call_count == 1
```

I need `.say()` to retain its original functionality.

Comment: I think a decorator function will be a good option here

Comment: Write two tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resorted to using `wraps=...` argument:

```
class Foo:
    def say_it(self):
        self.say()

    def say(self):
        print("Hello!")
        return 123


def test_call_count():
    with patch("Foo.say", wraps=Foo.say) as say_call:
        amount = Foo().say_it()
    assert amount == 123
    assert say_call.call_count == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but this should get you started (well, this exact snippet is untested - I've done similar hacks that worked properly):

```
def test_call_count():
    real_say = Foo.say.im_func
    call_count = [0]

    def patched_say(self, *args, **kw):
        call_count[0] += 1
        return real_say(self, *args, **kw)

    Foo.say = patched_say 
    amount = Foo().say_it()
    Foo.say = real_say

    assert amount == 123
    assert call_count[0] == 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use either `patch()` or a similar cleaner way.

Comment: What is "a similar cleaner way" ?